# Obfuscator xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, clang, obfuscation

has anyone used the Obfuscator 3.4? 
Well i've followed all the steps and configurations on their page (https://github.com/obfuscator-llvm/obfuscator/wiki/Installation), then i opened my xcode project and choose Obfuscator 3.4 on build settings, but every time i make a build the xcode exits unexpectedly.

When i try to see the report it appears like this:

" Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5B1008
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCahce/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-5069/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/BuildSystem/Runtime/PBXTargetBuildContent.m:1548
Details: commandPath should be a string, but is is nil
Object:  
..."

Has anyone experience this? Has anyone use this plugin?
I would really appreciate if someone could help or share ideas, this is really important and i've been trying on this for 2 days.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What?  Objective-C needs obfuscation??

Comment: Xcode 3 huh? maybe update your project settings.

Comment: @HotLicks, this app needs obfuscation, its a client requirement and a necessity due to the type of app.

Comment: Obfuscators are rarely trouble-free, and one suspects that they would be especially problematic with Objective-C.  I suspect you're on your own.

Comment: @BradAllred, its Xcode 5.1.1 and i've discovered the problem. So if in anytime of your life you are thinking of using Obfuscator 3.4 you have to know that arch like arm64 won't work, so you have to select only the arm7 and armv7 on projet build settings. 
You also have to know that to build the project you can't target the simulator, you have always to select an ios device to run or build.

Comment: I was talking about the `IDEXcode3ProjectSupport` and the like in your error message that you evidently didnt bother to read.

Comment: I evidently read it. So if you had read correctly my last comment i said "you have to select only the arm7 and armv7 on project build settings". So the the update you talked about was this fix, and was related to the IDEXcode3ProjectSupport...